# Terraform: trouble referencing for_each instances within another for_each resource created from a flattened object list with a lists attribute

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to create Azure AD directory role assignments by looping through an object array containing role name and a list attribute with the security groups. I figured out I first need to flatten it to access the lists per object. However, I'm now struggling to reference the security groups I have created in another for_each loop because it doesn't match the attributes names. This all because the azuread_directory_role_assignment resource only takes 1:1 associations.

These are the two variable arrays I've generated I intend to create the security groups and the Azure AD directory role assignments from:

```
{
  "variable": {
    "rbac-adorggroups": {
      "default": [
        {
          "adgroup-name": "tst-as-azp_platformowner-members",
          "adgroup-members": [],
          "adgroup-aadroleenabled": true
        },
        {
          "adgroup-name": "tst-as-azp_platformmanager-members",
          "adgroup-members": [],
          "adgroup-aadroleenabled": true
        },
        {
          "adgroup-name": "tst-as-azp_grc-members",
          "adgroup-members": [],
          "adgroup-aadroleenabled": true
        },
        {
          "adgroup-name": "tst-as-azp_ccc-members",
          "adgroup-members": [],
          "adgroup-aadroleenabled": true
        },
        {
          "adgroup-name": "tst-as-azp_platformops-members",
          "adgroup-members": [],
          "adgroup-aadroleenabled": true
        },
        {
          "adgroup-name": "tst-as-azp_networkops-members",
          "adgroup-members": [],
          "adgroup-aadroleenabled": true
        },
        {
          "adgroup-name": "tst-as-azp_securityops-members",
          "adgroup-members": [],
          "adgroup-aadroleenabled": true
        },
        {
          "adgroup-name": "tst-as-azp_iamops-members",
          "adgroup-members": [],
          "adgroup-aadroleenabled": true
        }
      ]
    },
    "rbac-aadroles": {
      "default": [
        {
          "aadrole-name": "Application Administrator",
          "aadrole-groups": [
            "tst-as-azp_iamops-members"
          ]
        },
        {
          "aadrole-name": "Authentication Administrator",
          "aadrole-groups": [
            "tst-as-azp_iamops-members"
          ]
        },
        {
          "aadrole-name": "Authentication Policy Administrator",
          "aadrole-groups": [
            "tst-as-azp_securityops-members"
          ]
        },
        {
          "aadrole-name": "Billing Administrator",
          "aadrole-groups": [
            "tst-as-azp_platformmanager-members"
          ]
        },
        {
          "aadrole-name": "Compliance Administrator",
          "aadrole-groups": [
            "tst-as-azp_securityops-members",
            "tst-as-azp_grc-members"
          ]
        },
        {
          "aadrole-name": "Conditional Access Administrator",
          "aadrole-groups": [
            "tst-as-azp_iamops-members"
          ]
        },
        {
          "aadrole-name": "Global Reader",
          "aadrole-groups": [
            "tst-as-azp_platforowner-members",
            "tst-as-azp_platformmanager-members",
            "tst-as-azp_grc-members",
            "tst-as-azp_ccc-members",
            "tst-as-azp_platformops-members",
            "tst-as-azp_securityops-members"
          ]
        },
        {
          "aadrole-name": "Guest Inviter",
          "aadrole-groups": [
            "tst-as-azp_platformmanager-members"
          ]
        },
        {
          "aadrole-name": "Hybrid Identity Administrator",
          "aadrole-groups": [
            "tst-as-azp_iamops-members"
          ]
        },
        {
          "aadrole-name": "Identity Governance Administrator",
          "aadrole-groups": [
            "tst-as-azp_securityops-members"
          ]
        },
        {
          "aadrole-name": "License Administrator",
          "aadrole-groups": [
            "tst-as-azp_platformmanager-members"
          ]
        },
        {
          "aadrole-name": "Privileged Authentication Administrator",
          "aadrole-groups": [
            "tst-as-azp_platformmanager-members",
            "tst-as-azp_securityops-members"
          ]
        },
        {
          "aadrole-name": "Privileged Role Administrator",
          "aadrole-groups": [
            "tst-as-azp_platformmanager-members",
            "tst-as-azp_securityops-members"
          ]
        },
        {
          "aadrole-name": "Security Administrator",
          "aadrole-groups": [
            "tst-as-azp_securityops-members"
          ]
        },
        {
          "aadrole-name": "User Administrator",
          "aadrole-groups": [
            "tst-as-azp_iamops-members"
          ]
        }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here's the flatten function I'm using to get to the list of security groups per role I want to loop trough a for_each with the azuread_directory_role_assignment resource:

```
locals {
    flattended_role_assignments = flatten([
        for assignment in var.rbac-aadroles : [
            for security-group in assignment.aadrole-groups : {
                role-name = assignment.aadrole-name
                role-group = security-group
            }
        ]
    ])
}
```

First I create the security groups which I want then to reference later on:

```
resource "azuread_group" "rbac-adorggroups" {
    for_each = {for org in var.rbac-adorggroups: org.adgroup-name => org}
    display_name = each.value.adgroup-name
    security_enabled = true
    assignable_to_role = each.value.adgroup-aadroleenabled
    members = toset([for member in each.value.adgroup-members: data.azuread_user.rbac-userids[(member)].object_id])
    prevent_duplicate_names = true
}
```

Now I activate the directory roles:

```
resource "azuread_directory_role" "aadr-enable" {
    for_each = {for role in var.rbac-aadroles: role.aadrole-name => role}
    display_name = each.value.aadrole-name
}
```

and finally create the role assignments:

```
resource "azuread_directory_role_assignment" "aadr-adorggroups" {
    for_each = {for assignment in local.flattended_role_assignments: "${assignment.role-name}-${assignment.role-group}" => assignment}
    role_id = azuread_directory_role.aadr-enable[each.value.role-name].template_id
    principal_object_id = azuread_group.rbac-adorggroups[*][each.value.role-group].object_id
    depends_on = [
        azuread_directory_role.aadr-enable,
        azuread_group.rbac-adorggroups
     ]
}
```

but this last bit gives me trouble on the reference for the principal_object_id:

```
 Error: Invalid index
│
│   on rbac-mainv3.tf line 60, in resource "azuread_directory_role_assignment" "aadr-adorggroups":
│   60:     principal_object_id = azuread_group.rbac-adorggroups[*][each.value.role-group].object_id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value.role-group is "tst-as-azp_platforowner-members"
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

What am I missing in referencing the security group correctly to assign it to the role? I've attempted with multiple referencing methods.

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably due to  ([*]) in for-each loop in the azuread_directory_role_assignment resource. Try removing that asteric * while referencing mapped values.

Code:

```
     resource "azuread_directory_role_assignment" "aadr-adorggroups" {
       for_each            = { for assignment in 
        local.flat_assignments :"${assignment.role-name}-${assignment.role-group}" => assignment }
       role_id             = azuread_directory_role.aadr-enable[each.value.role-name].id
       principal_object_id = azuread_group.rbac-adorggroups[each.value.role-group].id
     
       depends_on = [
         azuread_directory_role.aadr-enable,
         azuread_group.rbac-adorggroups
       ]
     }
```

[image]

Following  pattern can be used alternatlely to assign mapped roles to groups.

Example:

variables.tf

```
variable "group_mem" {
  type = map(object({
    members = list(string)
  }))
  default = {
    group1 = {
      members = ["myuser1", "myuser2"]
    },
    group2 = {
      members = ["myuser3"]
    }
  }
}

variable "role_assignments" {
  type = map(list(string))
  default = {
    Contributor = ["group1"],
    Reader      = ["group2"]
  }
}
```

main.tf:

```
resource "azuread_group" "example_group" {
  for_each = var.group_mem

  name = each.key
}

resource "azuread_directory_role" "example_role" {
  for_each = var.role_assignments

  role_name = each.key
}

resource "azuread_directory_role_assignment" "example_assignment" {
  for_each = var.role_assignments

  role_definition_id = azuread_directory_role.example_role[each.key].id
  principal_id       = azuread_group.example_group[each.value[0]].id
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But of course I've already tried omitting the splat [*], which gives me the error that the given key is a collection...
```
azuread_group.rbac-adorggroups is object with 8 attributes
each.value.role-group is "tst-as-azp_platforowner-members"

The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```
Moreover, your alternate approach oversimplifies my original variable, which then only has 1:1 associatons between role to group. That,s what I want to achieve with the flatten function, because my object array may have multiple groups per role.